# Maximum number of negative entries in a matrix with positive diagonal and given rank

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, matrices

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has positive entries on it main diagonal and $\mbox{rank}(A) =: d < n$. Then, what is the maximum number of many negative entries $A$ can contain?

If, in addition, $A$ is positive semidefinite (PSD), then using the fact that in $d$-dimensional space there are at most $d+1$ vectors with pairwise negative inner product and [Turán's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) from graph theory we can bound the number of negative entries by roughly $$\left(\frac{d-1}{d}\right) n^2$$

But what if $A$ is not PSD?

I've been stuck with this problem for a while. Any helpful reference is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have results for special d, e.g. d = 1 or d = N-1? (sorry, MathJax seems to be broken somehow...)

Comment: The case where $d=1$ is easy. When $d=N-1$, actually all the off-diagonal entries can be negative.

Comment: Sounds like d=N-2 might be the first “intermediate” case on the upper part of the range, then. Perhaps getting a formula for it would help.